# Búsquedas separadas por coma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta que funciona correctamente

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Sp_BuscarLoteUpdate]
@Condicion NVARCHAR(30),
@Condicion1 NVARCHAR(30)
AS
SELECT * FROM tblmvto_lotes WHERE codlote LIKE '%'+@Condicion+'%' AND  animal IN (SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(@Condicion1, ',') )
```

Lo que pasa es que la función **STRING_SPLIT** esta en  versiones superiores a 2014 SQL SERVER
mi pregunta es como puedo hacer esa misma función **(SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(@Condicion1, ','))** en sql 2014

lo que hace esa función es que pueda buscar varios datos seguidos por coma  pero en SQL SERVER 2014 no funciona así

Comment: Recomiendo leer este post y probar los posibles resultados [String_split SQL Server 2012](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/SQL/1708682-string_split-sql-server-2012.html)

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir un ejemplo del contenido de la tabla `tblmvto_lotes`? A ti seguramente te resulte familiar, pero a los demás, que no tenemos ni idea de en que estás trabajando, te aseguro que no.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución amigo